# Facebook app invite showing friends not from currently logged in account

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-app-invites

I added Facebook app invite with FBSDKAppInviteContent in my application and it's working fine. But when I switched Facebook account from my app, it is still showing friends list of  previous account that are login in my device . The friends list is not getting updated with new Facebook account.

Comment: Can I know how dod you switch the facebook account exactly?

Comment: log out from current Facebook app > log in with different user.